# Clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ObjC' - XCTests

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xcode8, xctest

I am trying to write unit test cases for the Objective-C project which has already created. Unit test case target has not selected at the time of project creations.
Now I have added the test case target to the app and the unit test case file also. When I ran the project got the build error saying **XCTest.h** file is not available. Now I added XCTest frames work in Build Phase tab of the App target.Now there is a new error saying

> clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ObjC'

What is the issue? Why am I getting this?

Comment: Search your project setting for `ObjC`.

Answer (score 0):

After some research This issue is figured out.

When I removed the ObjC from Other linker flags in XCode build setting of Test target and did a clean build and build the app.Then issue resolved.